# Control the title of the tab that an image is in using content-disposition?

Tags: http

I'm outputing an image via an HTTPHandler here is an example:

http://www.nfuonline.com/assets/1414

Here the image has a response header of:

```
content-disposition:inline; filename=4655e8cb-7cb7-421b-8b89-47c717d51697.gif
```

However when you view the image in a browser its title is shown as 1414. Is there a way that I can change this? Please not that the current code (which isn't live on the internet yet) uses a header name of Content-Disposition instead and that doesn't make a difference, I've also tried a shorter filename and I've tried wrapping the filename in quotes. Does anyone know what could be wrong with this?

Thanks,

Joe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However when you view the image in a browser its title is shown as 1414. Is there a way that I can change this?

Yes, by serving the image in an HTML document that has a proper `<title />` element. If you don't, the title to display is up to the browser.

You may help the browser by letting your URL end with the filename, say:

```
http://www.example.com/assets/1414/4655e8cb-7cb7-421b-8b89-47c717d51697.gif
```

Comment: So the filename in content disposition is only taken in to account when the file is actually downloaded?

Comment: @JoeNFU that depends on the browser. Nowhere in the HTTP spec it says _"The user agent window title should show the content-disposition filename"_, so you can only work with what _is_ specified.